# Manual configuration of 2sxc Content module

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I installed the 2sxc Content and App modules on a DNN8.0.3 environment. I could not run the auto-configure as the file it attempts to download contains some keywords blocked by our network. I obtained the file from outside the network and am trying to configure the module manually. This is all of the instructions the module provides. [image: This is all of the instructions the module provides]

This is how the admin section looks. 
[image]
It may be obvious to the developers, but not intuitive for the users how to install this file - http://autoinstall.2sexycontent.org/Packages/2SexyContent-GettingStarted-01.00.04.zip in any of those sections. I couldn't find any documentation on this either.

I hope the details above conform to StackOverflow requirements. I had to post a question here since the support team will not help me through email.

Comment: 2sxc is sending people to stack overflow to ask Non-development related questions, this is a horrible use of SO

Comment: @ChrisHammond I agree! As I was afraid this question was not fit for SO, I had to put the disclaimer to avoid getting downvoted or question getting locked.

Comment: @ChrisHammond i understand your concern - since 2sxc is itself a development system and most issues are code/dev related. But it is not a clear black/white situation. Most questions are actually dev questions, but for those which are not, it's not a clear cut case for the person asking the question. So for now I think this is a reasonable path.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you check your screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5ku3.jpg you'll see the app-tab, in there you'll find the import buttons.